# .htaccess deny files in subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to block access to "sub/folder/index.php", but not "index.php" anywhere else.

```
<Files index.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

works but blocks all "index.php" files.

```
<Files sub/folder/index.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

doesn't work. Do I need to use `<Directory>`?

**I don't want to create an .htaccess file in the sub/folder**

**I don't have access to httpd.conf**

**I don't want to block everything in sub/directory**

If it were that easy, I wouldn't be asking ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the simpliest rule is:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/sub/folder/index\.php$
```

RedirectMatch is in mod_alias module, that you certainly have. This does not implies mod_rewrite engine. Here we are simply telling apache that any access to sub/folder/index.php will generate a "403 forbidden" answer.

You can put that in a httpd.conf or in the root .htaccess (but really consider removing all .htaccess, it's bad, it's slow, it's sad that you do not have access to the real configuration files).

Comment: This works! Apparently `RedirectMatch` is handled separately from `RewriteRule`

Comment: If you want to disable access to every file in every subfolder do this: RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/*/*\.*$

Comment: Miha, I think that the best rule for all files would be simply /*$ in the end, this way files that don't have dots will also apply to this rule

Comment: I'm using this rule on all of my Wordpress sites htaccess now. Server logs were showing lots of attempts to access the theme index.php directly.  `RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/wp-content/themes/(.*)/index\.php$`

Answer (score 2):

I try creating another .htaccess in that sub/folder/ to block the access to that index.php.

"If you place a .htaccess file in a sub-folder, its directives will override the ones that you have in your site main folder."

This page has further information: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/htaccess.html

Comment: The article you linked is useful if this is the first time you've heard of the concept of `.htacess` files. Not so useful here.

Comment: Your question at the time was not stating whether you new all the possibilities you had with htaccess, that is why I gave you such a link.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a `.htaccess` file in the specific folder containing the files you want to protect?

**Edit:**

**Be careful, this actually does not work in a simple `.htaccess` file, see comments below. This will only work in an apache.conf file.**

<strike>This should to the trick for you without another `.htaccess` file:</strike>

```
<Directory sub/folder>
   <Files index.php>
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I don't want to do that of course, for reasons that are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Then yes, you will need to apply directoy rules. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: Oh, just stumbled upon that this only works in the apache.conf files and not .htaccess files itself... see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I've tried this (before the posting the question of course) and it just gives an Eternal Server Error.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite? If so you might consider rewriting that URL if it matches to sub/folder/index.php

Comment: See the answer by Joachim. `RewriteRule` doesn't work. `RedirectMatch` does though!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use file names in <Files> sections, not paths.

There are three options I can see;

- Put a .htaccess file in the same folder as the file.
- Put the configuration in apache.conf using a <Directory> directive and a <Files> directive. 
  <Directory> does not work in .htaccess files, only apache.conf
- Create a rewrite rule using mod_rewrite a'la;

-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sub/folder/index.php$ http://yoursite/index.locked
```

Will give a 404 on the file, if you want a permission denied, create a read protected file at the pointed to location.

Comment: The second one is inviable as well ;)

Comment: I've played around with this and it would work, only the sub-directory contains an .htaccess file as well with RewrieRules. So I'd need `RewriteOptions inherit` and a `RewriteBase` decleration in the parent but I can't supply that because my environment is dynamic. I always find it amazing how completely useless .htaccess is when you have modular structures.

Comment: Hm, I just did this without a .htaccess in the sub directory. Does the sub directory have a separate section in your apache.conf or similar that'd make apache not trust the uplevel file?

Comment: This is apparently default behavior. `RewriteRule`s in a parent `.htaccess` file are not applied unless you add `RewriteOptions inherit`. But then the rule doesn't fire because the `RewriteBase` is set to the child directory. I can't reset the `RewriteBase` because I don't know it (because of modularity). A solution would be to _generate_ .htaccess files when the application is deployed, but I feel this is more a design flaw than anything else, it's been around for quite some time after all.