# Restrict file write access to directory

Tags: file, .htaccess, file-access

Currently working on some project but having some security-issues with file writing access.

For my website I need to restrict write access for certain directories to be set to sub-files and folders of that directory only, I was told this could be done with htaccess only, so this is what I tried:

```
order deny, allow
deny from websitename.com/
allow from websitename.com/this_directory/
```

In other words: restrict write access for this_directory to files within it and within sub-directories of it. However, this htaccess ain't working... Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance, would be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: I don't know much about htaccess file, but how can you access websitename.com/this_directory/ if you tell to deny everything from the root.

Comment: Well I'm not sure either, but I thought since you do allow access from websitename.com/this_directory/ to itself, it should be possible, however denying access to it from outside directories. However right now all access from outside is still allowed (even using this htaccess)...

Comment: can this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801994/htaccess-deny-files-in-subfolders) help you out ?

Comment: Might indeed help, checking it out thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the restrict access by directory issue, thanks anyway!